# How can I separate admin menus?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I would like to separate administrator menus (the menus that appear after login as admin) from normal menus. I have to show admin menus in some other blocks. I don't like to use any modules for this, let me know how can done this with code,

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this without any code:

1. Go to *Site building* -> *Menus* -> *Add menu*.
2. Create your menu, let's say *Admin menu*, and save it.
3. Go into *Site building* -> *Menus* -> *Navigation*.
4. Click the *edit* link next to the *Administer* menu item.
5. Change the *Parent* to your new menu and save.

Your new menu will now contain the entire *Administer* menu tree, and it'll be out of the original *Navigation* menu. From there, you can move each part of the menu around to your liking.

This way is not without issues, though: there are still modules that depend on the *Administration* menu being in a specific place, and this messes with that.

I encourage you to re-think your aversion to modules: it's really against the spirit of Drupal. Almost everything under the sun has been already created as a Drupal module, and you're encouraged to reap the benefits of the open-source community.

For example, to avoid the pitfalls of the approach I outlined, there are two modules that can really help: the first one is [*Administration menu*](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu): enable it and that's it. The administer menu will disappear from the *Navigation* menu, and you'll have a new admin menu that'll appear on every page for easy access.

The second one is [*Menu block*](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block), which lets you create sub-menu blocks. If you have it enabled, you can:

1. Go to *Site Building* -> *Blocks* -> *Add menu block*.
2. Under *Parent*, select *Menu: Navigation* and *Item: --Administer*.
3. Save the block. You now have a block available that contains just the administration menu.

You'll now have the administration menu in a separate block to do with as you please.